# Unable to RDP to VM hosted in Windows 2016 Server

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, rdp, virtualbox, windows-server-2016

I have a windows 2016 server, which hosts a VM (Oracle Virtual Box). VM network setting is NAT with port forward. e.g. 192.168.10.17:5001 gets forward to 10.0.2.15:3389

**Here are steps I have tried:**

1. I can RDP to the Win2016 Server from any PC in the domain.

   e.g. RDP 192.168.10.17, all ok
2. I can't RDP to the VM that is inside the Wind2016 server.

   e.g. RDP 192.168.10.17:5001 -error: unable to connect
3. If I turn off Firewall - Domain profile on Win2016 server, the step 2 works. I can RDP to the VM.

**My conclusion from above tests**

Domain profile firewall is blocking the RDP connecting to VM hosted inside the Win2016 server.

Turning on both public profile and private profile has no problem at all.

**My Question**

Turning off the whole domain profile firewall just for RDP is not an ideal solution. It is better to have a special rule as an exception. Anybody knows which firewall rule might do the trick ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open a TCP and UDP port 5001 on winows server 2016 and let domain profile firewall be turned on. This should work. The reaon is that your client and 2016 both are on domain. you enabled firewall for rdp into 2016 but its not allowing connection on 5001 because firewall is on. opening this port will solve the issue.

Comment: Yes that was the reason. all good now. Thank you for the good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For the current setup, I would suggest you open the firewall for the RDP protocol, rather than a port.

However, if there is no specific reason for running VirtualBox instead of Hyper-V, I would recommend this instead, so traffic does not have to pass through the Windows server, but instead let the virtual network switch pass traffic to the right machine straight away.

I'm sure that the virtualbox does the same, but it makes sense using the built-in features for this unless VB is needed for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Create a rule in your `Windows Firewall` to allow incoming connections on port 5001

The following command creates a new rule:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="RDP Port forwarding" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=5001 profile=domain
```